# attaining the speed of light??

Tags: time, relativity

WHY our time would run slow if we move with the speed close or  equal to the speed of light, and is that time dilation restricted to only just '' time' ' or it affects our biological time also (does it stops or  slows down our ageing process) ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a photon have no mass and still travel at the speed of light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3541/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would travelling at relativistic speeds have any impact on human biology?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48502/)

Answer (score 1):

[Time dilation](http://physics.ucr.edu/~wudka/Physics7/Notes_www/node78.html) is a consequence of the observation that the speed of light (in a vacuum) is a constant.

Insofar as the human ageing process is a kind of clock it is also affected by this effect. Identical twins who meet after one of them has accellerated to an appreciable fraction of the speed of light will have eged by different amounts when they meet.